# JavaScript, include string not included with special characters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to ignore some string.

The idea is to check if the string to ignore is included in a list of strings separated by commas. When the string to ignore is "/healthCheck' (case 2) works ok, but in case 1, when the string has more special characters, is not working.

Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/pwfLou6e/7/

```js
const URLS_TO_IGNORE="/healthCheck,/socket.io//?EIO,/socket.io, /otherEndpoint"

// Case 1 not working
const endpointToIgnore = '/socket.io//?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=77qQ9HboF54_NtCdAAb';
const ignoreLogger = URLS_TO_IGNORE.includes(endpointToIgnore);
console.log(ignoreLogger); // false

// Case 2 working
const endpointToIgnore2 = '/healthCheck';
const ignoreLogger2 = URLS_TO_IGNORE.includes(endpointToIgnore2);
console.log(ignoreLogger2); // true

// Case 3 working
const endpointToIgnore3 = '/otherEndpoint';
const ignoreLogger3 = URLS_TO_IGNORE.includes(endpointToIgnore2);
console.log(ignoreLogger3); // true
```

How can Ignore the string: `/socket.io` ?

I need a way to valid that every string that starts with `/socket.io` despite what other characters are after, be included in the ignore function.

Comment: Take a look at `startsWith`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

You could split your `URLS_TO_IGNORE` by commas to get an array and check if the `endpointToIgnore` starts with any of them

Comment: But I need to find if ednpointToIgnore string is in the middle of the URLS_TO_IGNORE, not just at start

Comment: subparry was saying to split your urls by the , - that is the [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function. This separates the string into array entries (in your case with `const urlsArray = URLS_TO_IGNORE.split(',')` which you can then easily loop over.

Comment: Added as answer with example

Comment: @CBroe fixed the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `startsWith` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith You could split your `URLS_TO_IGNORE` by commas to get an array and check if the endpointToIgnore starts with any of them

```js
const URLS_TO_IGNORE="/healthCheck,/socket.io//?EIO,/socket.io, /otherEndpoint".split(',')

const endpointToIgnore = '/socket.io//?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OPVH0sr&sid=77qQ9HboF54_NtCdAAb'

const ignoreLogger = URLS_TO_IGNORE.some((path)=>endpointToIgnore.startsWith(path));
```

Comment: The problem is that in your case, URLS_TO_IGNORE is an array. The value of my URLS_TO_IGNORE comes from a secret environment as string from an external service. I'll have to convert that separated comma string into the array to do what you suggest, but I guess I can, thanks

Comment: I just put it as an array for brevity. 
Edited the answer to better reflect your question.

Answer (score 1):

use the `test()` method of the regular expression to check if the string matches the pattern that starts with "/socket.io"

```js
const URLS_TO_IGNORE = "/healthCheck,/socket.io//?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=77qQ9HboF54_NtCdAAb,/socket.io, /otherEndpoint";

// Case 1 working
const endpointToIgnore = '/socket.io//?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OPVH0sr&sid=77qQ9HboF54_NtCdAAb';
const ignoreLogger = URLS_TO_IGNORE.split(",").some(url => /^\/socket\.io.*/.test(url) && endpointToIgnore.includes(url) );
console.log(ignoreLogger); // true

// Case 2 working
const endpointToIgnore2 = '/healthCheck';
const ignoreLogger2 = URLS_TO_IGNORE.includes(endpointToIgnore2);
console.log(ignoreLogger2); // true

// Case 3 working
const endpointToIgnore3 = '/otherEndpoint';
const ignoreLogger3 = URLS_TO_IGNORE.includes(endpointToIgnore2);
console.log(ignoreLogger3); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dummy URL and look at the pathname

```js
const URLS_TO_IGNORE = ["/healthCheck","/socket.io","/otherEndpoint"];
const checkUrl = path => {
  const url = new URL(`https://dummyURL.com${path}`);
  const pathname = url.pathname;
  const ignore = URLS_TO_IGNORE.some(pn => pathname.startsWith(pn))
  console.log("PN:",pathname,"\nign",ignore)
  return ignore
};  


console.log(checkUrl('/socket.io//?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OPVH0sr&sid=77qQ9HboF54_NtCdAAb'));
console.log(checkUrl('/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OPVH0sr&sid=77qQ9HboF54_NtCdAAb'));
console.log(checkUrl('/okendpoint'));
console.log(checkUrl('/healthCheck'));
console.log(checkUrl('/otherEndpoint'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let text = "";
    const check_urls = ['/socket.io//?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OPVH0sr&sid=77qQ9HboF54_NtCdAAb','/healthCheck']
    const urs= '/socket.io//?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OPVH0sr&sid=77qQ9HboF54_NtCdAAb';

    check_urls.forEach(ifun);

    function ifun(item, index) {
        text += index + ": " + item +" == "+ urs.includes(item);
    }
    console.log(text);
```